# copy and paste as negative value

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed below code and i want that it should paste the value as negative instead of positive value. I looked around but nothing similar found.

It should be negative `ws.Cells(r, "I").Value`

```
Sub copyandpasteasnegative()

Dim ws          As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, r As Long
Set ws = Sheet1

LastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
For r = 2 To LastRow

If ws.Cells(r, "B") = "KIO" Then

ws.Cells(r, "I").Value = ws.Cells(r + 1, "I").Value

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please, think before asking.... Would this not be solve using an extra minus sign somewhere ?

Comment: `- ws.Cells(r, "I").Value` added this but text goes red.

Comment: `ws.Ceells(r, "I").Value = -1 * ws.Cells(r + 1, "I").Value`. Might be worth using `IsNumeric` before attempting to multiply.

Comment: I was changing `ws.Ceells(r, "I").Value` with negative values Thank you @BigBen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple multiplication:

```
ws.Cells(r, "I").Value = -1 * ws.Cells(r + 1, "I").Value
```

Probably best to use `IsNumeric` before attempting to multiply:

```
With ws.Cells(r + 1, "I")
    If IsNumeric(.Value) Then
        ws.Cells(r, "I").Value = .Value * -1 
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by changing only one line. Try this:

```
ws.Cells(r, "I").Value = 0 - ws.Cells(r + 1, "I").Value
```